# How to train a supervised sequence classifier like CRF, if we have to extract start date and end date from a user query in python

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have to build a chatbot, in python in which a user can apply for a leave. I want to extract start date and end date from a users query. I did some research on couple of algorithms and found CRF Entity Extractor as the best one. I now want to see a similar implemented solution in python, which I can use it as a reference. I would like to see an end to end solution right from training dataset to predicting start and end dates from query. Kindly help.

For example:

1.query: "I want to take leave from 2nd April to 5th April."
Predicted dates: "02-04-2020" and "05-04-2020"

1.query: "I want to take leave on next Monday"
Predicted dates: "09-03-2020"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that building a model using CRF is the best approach here. It's going to require quite a bit of training data and effort to get it working like you want. Dates are pretty structured in most cases so there are more straightforward approaches to extracting them. [Stanford's SUTime library](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml), for instance, does exactly what you're describing in your question. Although is is Java based there is a [Python wrapper](https://github.com/FraBle/python-sutime) for it. For example, for the following input:

`query = 'I need a desk for tomorrow from 2pm to 3pm'`

Using the SUTime Python wrapper, this is the parsed result you'd get:

```
[
    {
        "end": 26,
        "start": 18,
        "text": "tomorrow",
        "type": "DATE",
        "value": "2016-10-14"
    },
    {
        "end": 42,
        "start": 27,
        "text": "from 2pm to 3pm",
        "type": "DURATION",
        "value": {
            "begin": "T14:00",
            "end": "T15:00"
        }
    }
]
```